# nest two or more php scripts in a GET variable

Tags: php, html

I've created a little script miniature.php witch echo a thumbnail from the image given by GET.

Another script cover.php echo the cover image of a .mp3 file.

I use both like this on my pages:

```
<img src="miniature.php?maxWidth=300&img=img/image.jpg" />
<img src="cover.php?file=files/beat it.mp3" />
```

Both works well.

But I would like to make a miniature from a cover, and I may need something like this:

```
<img src="miniature.php?maxWidth=300&img=cover.php?file=files/beat it.mp3" />
```

And... this does not work.
Is it possible to do something like this without saving the cover image before sending it to miniature ?

Comment: Wouldn't the most straightforward way to do this be actually editing your PHP script, and creating a third type that does both things?

Comment: Depends on what `miniature.php` does and you need to properly encode your URI parameters (` ` => `%20`, second `?` => `%3F`).

Comment: Marcel: good idea but still not working.

Comment: Pekka: You're right but I was wondering if the thing could work like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using file_get_content (or similar function) in your miniature.php using full encoded url of cover.php it is possible. Result url should be something like:

```
<img src="miniature.php?maxWidth=300&img=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2Fcover.php%3Ffile%3Dfiles%252Fbeat%2520it.mp3" />
```

Note that you need to encode files/beat it.mp3 two time.

Comment: @manuAcl Did you made file name encoded two times?! It is very important. One time alone and one time with address of cover.php

Comment: I tried again like this:
$img = 'miniature.php?maxSize=175&img='.urlencode('http://mysite.com/cover.php?file='.urlencode(UPLOAD_DIR.$data['file_name']));

gives me this url :
miniature.php?maxSize=175&img=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fcover.php%3Ffile%3Duploads%252F1.mp3

It works with "1.mp3", but not with "06 filename.mp3"

Comment: I finally tried like this, and it works well:
`if ( FALSE !== ($cont = file_get_contents( $url )) )
{
 $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
 $mime = substr( $finfo->buffer($cont), 0, strpos( $finfo->buffer($cont), ';' ) );

 $imgBig = imagecreatefromstring($cont);
 $size = array ( 'w' => imagesx($imgBig), 'h' => imagesy($imgBig) );
 
 [...]
}`

Comment: At the end, I added a function on my miniature script that calls the functions of cover.php, and I create the image with imagecreatefromstring : `$fileTab = getCover($file);

 $newHeight = (isset($_GET['maxSize']) && $_GET['maxSize'] != '')?$_GET['maxSize']:175;
 $mime = $fileTab['mime'];
 $cont = $fileTab['data'];

 $imgBig = imagecreatefromstring($cont);
 $size = array ( 'w' => imagesx($imgBig), 'h' => imagesy($imgBig) );

 $ratio = $size['w'] / $size['h'];

 $newSize = array( 'w' => $newHeight * $ratio, 'h' => $newHeight );` getCover() returns array('mime'=>'mime t', 'data'=>'data image')